# Suppose that $f(z) = \frac{z}{1-z}$. Use Cauchy-Riemann Equations to determine the analyticity of $f(z)$. Then find the derivative of $f(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, analyticity, cauchy-riemann-equations

can anyone help me in solving this question? I have tried expressing $z=x+iy$ and multiplying the conjugate to numerator and denominator. However, the expansion and differentiation are too tedious. Is there an easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(z) = \frac{z}{1-z} = \frac{x+iy}{1-x-iy} \cdot \frac{1-x+iy}{1-x+iy} = \frac{x-x^2-y^2 + iy}{(1-x)^2 + y^2}$$
Let $$u(x,y) = \frac{x-x^2-y^2}{(1-x)^2 + y^2}$$
and $$v(x,y) = \frac{y}{(1-x)^2 + y^2}$$
Then, $f = u + iv$. I have done the messy part of the calculation for you. I leave it to you to check whether or not the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold, and comment on the differentiability of $u,v: \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. These are straightforward computations since $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are known. Note that $f$ is defined only for $z\ne 1$, so $x = 1$ and $y = 0$ are not permitted.

---

Edit $1$: You can compute the partial derivatives using the quotient rule. You can verify your calculations with the following:
$$u_x = \frac{x^2- 2x -y^2 + 1}{((1-x)^2 + y^2)^2}$$
$$u_y = \frac{2(x-1)y}{((1-x)^2 + y^2)^2}$$
$$v_x = \frac{2(1-x)y}{((1-x)^2 + y^2)^2}$$
$$v_y = \frac{x^2- 2x -y^2 + 1}{((1-x)^2 + y^2)^2}$$

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. Actually, I have already done up till this step. I had difficulty in doing partial derivatives, as I am not sure whether to use the quotient rule or which other rule for it. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: The quotient rule will work. Could you post what you have tried with the quotient rule? See my edit too. You can try to find $v_x = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ and $v_y = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$. @MingFengTay

Comment: How do I insert photos? I am new to this. Seems like I can only type.

Comment: I have solved the question already. Since the CR equations are satisfied, am I right to say that f(z) is differentiable and analytic everywhere except at z=1? And my f'(z) would be Ux + iVx.

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to express z in terms of r and θ, will it be easier to solve?

Comment: CR equations alone are not enough, you also need to check the real differentiability of $f$, i.e. whether $u, v$ are differentiable. However, that is clear. I don't think it would be any easier with $r, \theta$, but you can try. If the answer helped you, feel free to upvote/accept it. @MingFengTay

Comment: Thanks buddy. I have already accept it, but I can't upvote because I'm new. I think I need at least 15 reputation to upvote. Anyways, if you're free, can you take a look at my other question related to complex numbers as well?